# How pass items from ref ObjectId's?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

[image]I trying to build a small personal betting site. I managed to get Arrays of ObjectId's in every collection refering to on another. 
But now I'm suffering to get the items from this collections into the view pages. how can I get more than only the ObjectId's and pass the items. 
I was looking at .populate(). is this the way to go? If so, can I, in this case the users with the info from the guess schema (that referces to match schema )

```
//route//


router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("guess")
    .exec(function(err,foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("users/show",{user:foundUser});
    }
 });
});


-----------------------
//viewPage//


<%user.guessList.forEach(function(guess){%>
  <div> <%= guess %></div> //need items of this guesses
<% }) %>
------------------
```

Schemas as picture attached

Comment: Hey there, I cannot say about the other users of this site, but for me, I need more info as so I can help you. Can you explain better what you want?

Comment: When you use `populate("guess")`, I am not sure it is correct since you have no `Guess` at `User`. In other to populate, you need to have the model you want to populate in the schema you want to populate.  See here an example of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727064/mongoose-populate-in-array-of-custom-objects/60730415#60730415

Comment: You either need to fix several things on your code or explain better what you want.

Comment: The idea of the site is: users can makes guesses on football matches. The users database will contain an array with all the guesses they did and the Match database will contain all the matches played with there teams/score and an array of guessesID's this guessesID's refere to de GuessModel that contains the guess/ the userID/ matchID so every model contains references to other models, that part works. But now If I for example try to get an overview of all the guesse made by a user I should get the items of these id. Getting the ID's seems to work but they don't contain the items.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood what you want, but if I did, you need to fix your schemas in other to achieve what you want.  I will try to add them, and you test them yourself; you may need to post other questions depending on the complexity.

When you say "The users database will contain an array with all the guesses they did". I believe this is what you want:

**First suggested modification**

```
guesslist: [{ type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "Guess" }];// this will make possible for you to populate with Guess models
```

And when you `populate` try this:

```
populate("guesslist");//it should be the name of the field to be populated
```